# How to use ionic popup?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button.

```
        <button type="button" class="button button-calm   list-inset" 
        ng-click="disable()">
            Delete
        </button>
```

When i click this button , i need to show a popup with 2 button. Cancel and 
Disable.
When i click disable the popup should hide and the first button should be disabled.
How to do that?
I simply need to disable the first button with a confirmation message,which is provided by a ionic popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your HTML :

```
<button class="button button-dark button-block" ng-click="disable()" ng-disabled="ko == true">
        Delete
      </button>
```

and in your controller you set up the variable like this  : `$scope.ko = false;` 
and your function in your controller to disable the button should be like this :

```
    var popup = $ionicPopup.show({
              title: 'disable',
              scope: $scope,
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Cancel',
                  type: 'button-default',
                  onTap: function (e) {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'OK',
                  type: 'button-dark',

   onTap: function (e) {
                return true;
              }
            }
          ]
        });

        popup.then(function (popRes) {
            if(popRes){
              $scope.ko = true;
              console.log("disable");
            }
        })
```

Hope it help you :). Don't forget to add the $ionicPopover in your controller

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="button" class="button button-calm   list-inset" 
        ng-click="disable()">
            Delete
        </button>
```

you have to put this code on your controller,

```
$scope.disable= function () {
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Delete',
            template: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'
        });

        confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
            if (res) {
                console.log('Deleted !');
            } else {
                console.log('Deletion canceled !');
            }
        });
    };
```

And also inject ($scope, $ionicPopup) in your controller.